# What is the source for pushing away the convert three times?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

What is the source for pushing away the convert three times?

I'm also interested in the exact quote.

Comment: See Yevamot 47ab for this topic I didn't find exactly if there is a rule to pushing away but to teach hard mitsvot

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90436/source-for-discouraging-converts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's in the Midrash [[Ruth Rabbah 2:16]](https://www.sefaria.org/Ruth_Rabbah.2.16?lang=bi):

Rabbi Shmuel bar Nahmani said in the name of Rav Yehudah ben Hanina: Three times is it written [in the Book of Ruth] "turn back", corresponding to the three times that a would-be convert is repulsed;

[Ruth 1:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16453#v8)

> וַתֹּ֤אמֶר נָֽעֳמִי֙ לִשְׁתֵּ֣י כַלֹּתֶ֔יהָ לֵ֣כְנָה שֹּׁ֔בְנָה
>   אִשָּׁ֖ה לְבֵ֣ית אִמָּ֑הּ יַ֣עַשׂ (כתיב יַ֣עַשׂה) יְהֹוָ֤ה עִמָּכֶם֙
>   חֶ֔סֶד כַּֽאֲשֶׁ֧ר עֲשִׂיתֶ֛ם עִם־הַמֵּתִ֖ים וְעִמָּדִֽי:
>
> And Naomi said to [Ruth and Orpah], Go, return each of you to her
>   mother's house

[Ruth 1:11](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16453#v11)

> וַתֹּ֤אמֶר נָֽעֳמִי֙ שֹׁ֣בְנָה בְנֹתַ֔י לָ֥מָּה תֵלַ֖כְנָה עִמִּ֑י
>   הַֽעוֹד־לִ֤י בָנִים֙ בְּֽמֵעַ֔י וְהָי֥וּ לָכֶ֖ם לַֽאֲנָשִֽׁים:
>
> And Naomi said, Turn back, my daughters; why will you go with me?

[Ruth 1:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16453#v12)

> שֹׁ֤בְנָה בְנֹתַי֙ לֵ֔כְן ָ כִּ֥י זָקַ֖נְתִּי מִֽהְי֣וֹת לְאִ֑ישׁ
>   כִּ֤י אָמַ֨רְתִּי֙ יֶשׁ־לִ֣י תִקְוָ֔ה גַּ֣ם הָיִ֤יתִי הַלַּ֨יְלָה֙
>   לְאִ֔ישׁ וְגַ֖ם יָלַ֥דְתִּי בָנִֽים:
>
> Turn back, my daughters, go your way.

but if he persists after that, he is accepted.

Ruth persisted:

[Ruth 1:18](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16453#v18)

> וַתֵּ֔רֶא כִּֽי־מִתְאַמֶּ֥צֶת הִ֖יא לָלֶ֣כֶת אִתָּ֑הּ וַתֶּחְדַּ֖ל
>   לְדַבֵּ֥ר אֵלֶֽיהָ:
>
> When [Naomi] saw that [Ruth] was determined to go with her, she
>   stopped [objecting].

-R. Isaac said: …A man should rebuff with his left hand, but bring near with the right.

Comment: The q asked for an exact quote, but this appears to be a translation.